# Tmux ignores window-status-style

Tags: tmux

I have the following in my `tmux.conf` file:

```
set -g window-status-style fg=colour234,bg=colour252
set -g window-status-activity-style fg=red,bg=yellow
set -g window-status-current-style fg=yellow,bg=green
set -g window-status-bell-style fg=colour234,bg=colour252
```

But whenever I source the file, or setup another session, it ignores my setting. Am I doing something wrong?

If I excplicity set the format:

```
set -g window-status-format "#[fg=colour234,bg=colour252]#[fg=colour235,bg=colour252,bold] #I: #W "
set -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour234,bg=blue]#[fg=black,bg=blue,noreverse,bold] #I: #W "
```

Then that change is reflected. Ignore the fact the colors are different as I just wanted something that was obvious if it changed.

I'm using tmux 1.9a

```
→ tmux -V
tmux 1.9a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you must still explicitly set the `format` too.

```
set -g window-status-format "#I: #W "
```

After editing that, setting `style` works as expected.